# bind gridview when column doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to bind a gridview from a datasource based on a SQL SELECT.

However, sometimes, a column will not exist on the datasource, depending on the data brought back from the statement. I only want one gridview.

How would I go about handling the binding in such a way that an error will not be thrown upon `GridView1.DataBind()`?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure how you're doing this but you can check columns with code a bit like this:

```
DataTable dt = GetMyDataFromDatabase();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (!dt.Columns.Contains("MyColumn"))
    {
        //do whatever, maybe add the missing column?...
        dt.Columns.Add("MyColumn", typeof(String));
    }
}
```

The other option would be to not define the columns on the ASPX and have it all defined in the codebehind off `RowDataBound` and `RowCreated` events.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make sure the columns are always present in every query result. You can avoid the errors by inserting dummy columns if needed.

If for example this is your default query

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC FROM yourDB
```

You can insert a dummy column like this if it is missing `columnB`

```
SELECT columnA, NULL AS columnB, columnC FROM yourDB
```

Or if you are missing columnA and it is an integer that has to have a value

```
SELECT 0 AS columnA, columnB, columnC FROM yourDB
```

Another option is to ONLY use `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` in the GridView. But this will give you less control over the design and layout.